# WARNING 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing

Tags: java, maven, warnings, maven-central

I successfully deployed my Maven artifact to the Central Repository. However, I saw this warning when I ran `mvn release:perform`:

```
[INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory /Users/miguelvelez/Documents/Programming/Java/Projects/messages/target/checkout
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[INFO] [WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'activateByDefault' (position: START_TAG seen ...<activation>\n            <activateByDefault>... @261:32)  @ /usr/bin/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/settings.xml, line 261, column 32
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mijecu25:messages:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] [WARNING]
```

The `<activateByDefault>` warning has been solved. But I am not sure about the missing plugin.

Here is my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mijecu25</groupId>
    <artifactId>messages</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messages</name>
    <description>Library with messages for debugging</description>
    <url>https://github.com/mijecu25/messages</url>
    <inceptionYear>2016</inceptionYear>
    <organization>
        <name>Mijecu25</name>
        <url>http://www.mijecu25.com</url>
    </organization>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/mijecu25/messages.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:mijecu25/messages.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/mijecu25/messages</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>miguelvelezmj25</id>
            <name>Miguel Velez</name>
            <email>miguelvelez@mijecu25.com</email>
            <url>http://www.mijecu25.com/miguelvelez/</url>
            <roles>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus snapshot repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>

        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus release repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>  

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <passphrase>${gpg.passphrase}</passphrase>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>xml</format>
                    <maxmem>256m</maxmem>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
                    <repoToken>${env.coveralls_repo_token}</repoToken>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

AS you can see, I am not using the `maven-deploy-plugin`. Do you know what the warning means?

**EDIT:** In the comments, it was suggested that I fix the error in the `settings.xml` file. This is the new output after I did so:

```
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mijecu25:messages:jar:1.0.1
[INFO] [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[INFO] [WARNING] 
[INFO] [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] [WARNING]
```

Any further ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: in the warning it's mentionned : `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.` and you have a problem in your `settings.xml` as indicated : `[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[INFO] [WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'activateByDefault' (position: START_TAG seen ...<activation>\n            <activateByDefault>... @261:32)  @ /usr/bin/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/settings.xml, line 261, column 32
[INFO] [WARNING] 
`

Comment: Right! I already fixed that issue in the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: First you need to fix the errors in your settings.xml file which should not be the one in the maven distribution....or better replace with the original one. If you need to customize your settings.xml put it into your user home `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` ..

Comment: So you think that if I fix that error in the `settings.xml` file, it will fix the warning with the `maven-deploy-plugin`?

Comment: I fixed the error from the `settings.xml` file and I pasted the new output.

Answer (score -1):

windows -> preferences->maven->user setting-> now give correct location of settings.xml 
setting.xml file which present in mavenfolder 
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\conf\settings.xml